# MySQL server has gone away - in exactly 60 seconds

Tags: php, mysql, timeout

I recently discovered that a sql query that was running fine earlier is now timing out after 60 seconds and throwing an error. The query is slow but runs as part of a nightly job so that's not a problem in itself (so please don't suggest I optimize it).

I'm able to reproduce the error consistently by running "select SLEEP(120);" from PHP as shown below. However, running the same statement from a MySQL client is successful (returns 0). I've tried adjusting wait_timeout (set to 28800), but have had no luck. I've also rebooted both the db server and machine itself.

The fact that it always times out at exactly 60 seconds suggests to me that it is likely to be a setting and not a limited resources issue.

I'm running:
Windows Server 2003
MySql 5.1.36-community
PHP 5.3

Below are my test code, the output and the results from SHOW VARIABLES

Thanks!

CODE:

```
set_error_handler("sqlErrorHandler");
set_time_limit(12000);


$link = mysql_connect("$MYSQL_Host","$MYSQL_User","$MYSQL_Pass");
mysql_select_db($MYSQL_db, $link);

echo "mysql_ping = " . (mysql_ping($link) ? "LIVE" : "DEAD") . "<br /><br />"; 

$sql = "SELECT SLEEP(120);";

$start = microtime(true);
mysql_query($sql, $link);

echo "**query done**<br />";
allDone();

function allDone(){
 global $start, $sql;

 $end = microtime(true);
 echo "sql : $sql<br />";
 echo "elapsed : " . ($end - $start) . "<br />";
 echo "<br />";
}

function sqlErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
 global $link;
 echo "Error : $errno<br />$errstr<br />";
 echo "mysql_ping : " . (mysql_ping($link) ? "LIVE" : "DEAD") . "<br />"; 
 echo "<br />";

 allDone();
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
mysql_ping = LIVE

Error : 2
mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: MySQL server has gone away
mysql_ping : DEAD

sql : SELECT SLEEP(120);
elapsed : 60.051116943359

Error : 2
mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Error reading result set's header
mysql_ping : DEAD

sql : SELECT SLEEP(120);
elapsed : 60.0511469841

**query done**
sql : SELECT SLEEP(120);
elapsed : 60.051155090332
```

SHOW VARIABLES:

```
Variable_name=Value
auto_increment_increment=1
auto_increment_offset=1
autocommit=ON
automatic_sp_privileges=ON
back_log=50
basedir=C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\
big_tables=OFF
binlog_cache_size=32768
binlog_format=STATEMENT
bulk_insert_buffer_size=8388608
character_set_client=utf8
character_set_connection=utf8
character_set_database=latin1
character_set_filesystem=binary
character_set_results=utf8
character_set_server=latin1
character_set_system=utf8
character_sets_dir=C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\share\\charsets\\
collation_connection=utf8_general_ci
collation_database=latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server=latin1_swedish_ci
completion_type=0
concurrent_insert=1
connect_timeout=10
datadir=C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Application Data\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\Data\\
date_format=%Y-%m-%d
datetime_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
default_week_format=0
delay_key_write=ON
delayed_insert_limit=100
delayed_insert_timeout=300
delayed_queue_size=1000
div_precision_increment=4
engine_condition_pushdown=ON
error_count=0
event_scheduler=OFF
expire_logs_days=0
flush=OFF
flush_time=1800
foreign_key_checks=ON
ft_boolean_syntax=+ -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len=84
ft_min_word_len=4
ft_query_expansion_limit=20
ft_stopword_file=(built-in)
general_log=OFF
general_log_file=C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Application Data\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\Data\\p1.log
group_concat_max_len=1024
have_community_features=YES
have_compress=YES
have_crypt=NO
have_csv=YES
have_dynamic_loading=YES
have_geometry=YES
have_innodb=YES
have_ndbcluster=NO
have_openssl=DISABLED
have_partitioning=YES
have_query_cache=YES
have_rtree_keys=YES
have_ssl=DISABLED
have_symlink=YES
identity=0
ignore_builtin_innodb=OFF
init_connect=
init_file=
init_slave=
innodb_adaptive_hash_index=ON
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2097152
innodb_autoextend_increment=8
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=96468992
innodb_checksums=ON
innodb_commit_concurrency=0
innodb_concurrency_tickets=500
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir=D:\\MySQL Datafiles\\
innodb_doublewrite=ON
innodb_fast_shutdown=1
innodb_file_io_threads=4
innodb_file_per_table=OFF
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_flush_method=
innodb_force_recovery=0
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size=1048576
innodb_log_file_size=19922944
innodb_log_files_in_group=2
innodb_log_group_home_dir=.\\
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=90
innodb_max_purge_lag=0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups=1
innodb_open_files=300
innodb_rollback_on_timeout=OFF
innodb_stats_on_metadata=ON
innodb_support_xa=ON
innodb_sync_spin_loops=20
innodb_table_locks=ON
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
innodb_thread_sleep_delay=10000
innodb_use_legacy_cardinality_algorithm=ON
insert_id=0
interactive_timeout=28800
join_buffer_size=131072
keep_files_on_create=OFF
key_buffer_size=50331648
key_cache_age_threshold=300
key_cache_block_size=1024
key_cache_division_limit=100
language=C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\share\\english\\
large_files_support=ON
large_page_size=0
large_pages=OFF
last_insert_id=0
lc_time_names=en_US
license=GPL
local_infile=ON
log=OFF
log_bin=OFF
log_bin_trust_function_creators=OFF
log_bin_trust_routine_creators=OFF
log_error=C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Application Data\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\Data\\p1.err
log_output=FILE
log_queries_not_using_indexes=OFF
log_slave_updates=OFF
log_slow_queries=OFF
log_warnings=1
long_query_time=10.000000
low_priority_updates=OFF
lower_case_file_system=ON
lower_case_table_names=1
max_allowed_packet=1048576
max_binlog_cache_size=4294963200
max_binlog_size=1073741824
max_connect_errors=10
max_connections=800
max_delayed_threads=20
max_error_count=64
max_heap_table_size=16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads=20
max_join_size=18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data=1024
max_prepared_stmt_count=16382
max_relay_log_size=0
max_seeks_for_key=4294967295
max_sort_length=1024
max_sp_recursion_depth=0
max_tmp_tables=32
max_user_connections=0
max_write_lock_count=4294967295
min_examined_row_limit=0
multi_range_count=256
myisam_data_pointer_size=6
myisam_max_sort_file_size=107374182400
myisam_recover_options=OFF
myisam_repair_threads=1
myisam_sort_buffer_size=12582912
myisam_stats_method=nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap=OFF
named_pipe=OFF
net_buffer_length=16384
net_read_timeout=30
net_retry_count=10
net_write_timeout=80
new=OFF
old=OFF
old_alter_table=OFF
old_passwords=OFF
open_files_limit=2048
optimizer_prune_level=1
optimizer_search_depth=62
optimizer_switch=index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on
pid_file=C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Application Data\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\Data\\p1.pid
plugin_dir=C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\lib/plugin
port=3306
preload_buffer_size=32768
profiling=OFF
profiling_history_size=15
protocol_version=10
pseudo_thread_id=3230
query_alloc_block_size=8192
query_cache_limit=1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit=4096
query_cache_size=33554432
query_cache_type=ON
query_cache_wlock_invalidate=OFF
query_prealloc_size=8192
rand_seed1=
rand_seed2=
range_alloc_block_size=4096
read_buffer_size=65536
read_only=OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size=262144
relay_log=
relay_log_index=
relay_log_info_file=relay-log.info
relay_log_purge=ON
relay_log_space_limit=0
report_host=
report_password=
report_port=3306
report_user=
rpl_recovery_rank=0
secure_auth=OFF
secure_file_priv=
server_id=0
shared_memory=OFF
shared_memory_base_name=MYSQL
skip_external_locking=ON
skip_networking=OFF
skip_show_database=OFF
slave_compressed_protocol=OFF
slave_exec_mode=STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir=C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP
slave_net_timeout=3600
slave_skip_errors=OFF
slave_transaction_retries=10
slow_launch_time=2
slow_query_log=OFF
slow_query_log_file=C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Application Data\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\Data\\p1-slow.log
sort_buffer_size=262144
sql_auto_is_null=ON
sql_big_selects=ON
sql_big_tables=OFF
sql_buffer_result=OFF
sql_log_bin=ON
sql_log_off=OFF
sql_log_update=ON
sql_low_priority_updates=OFF
sql_max_join_size=18446744073709551615
sql_mode=
sql_notes=ON
sql_quote_show_create=ON
sql_safe_updates=OFF
sql_select_limit=18446744073709551615
sql_slave_skip_counter=
sql_warnings=OFF
ssl_ca=
ssl_capath=
ssl_cert=
ssl_cipher=
ssl_key=
storage_engine=InnoDB
sync_binlog=0
sync_frm=ON
system_time_zone=Eastern Daylight Time
table_definition_cache=256
table_lock_wait_timeout=50
table_open_cache=619
table_type=InnoDB
thread_cache_size=38
thread_handling=one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack=196608
time_format=%H:%i:%s
time_zone=SYSTEM
timed_mutexes=OFF
timestamp=1256827484
tmp_table_size=16777216
tmpdir=C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP
transaction_alloc_block_size=8192
transaction_prealloc_size=4096
tx_isolation=REPEATABLE-READ
unique_checks=ON
updatable_views_with_limit=YES
version=5.1.36-community
version_comment=MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine=ia32
version_compile_os=Win32
wait_timeout=28800
warning_count=0
```

Comment: What happens if you run the SHOW VARIABLES query via a php script. Do the timeout values change?

Comment: I ran SHOW VARIABLES from PHP and the timeout settings are the same

Comment: Does anything show up in the mysql log when this happens?

Comment: nope, no entries in the error log for today. Other log files do not appear to exist

Comment: +1 for `gone in 60 seconds`

Comment: Opened this question just to see if anybody made the reference. +1

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The php option `mysql.connect_timeout` is the reason for this. It's not only used for connect timeout, but as well as waiting for the first answer from the server. You can increase it like this:

```
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 300);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
```

Comment: I thought that was going to work, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you set it before connecting or after?

Comment: before. First line of the script

Comment: and I did an ini_get to verify the new value

Comment: Try this with it if you're connecting via a socket (eg. localhost):

ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 60);

Comment: YES! Adding ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300) did it. Thanks!!

Comment: Save my day, increasing 'default_socket_timeout' from 60 to 300 in php.ini did the trick.

Comment: `default_socket_timeout` is the way to go even if the connection is TCP/IP and not socket file based.

Comment: Check also `wait_timeout` in mysql configs

Answer (score 10):

When I ran into this problem, it wasn't caused by wait_timeout (which was set to the default 8 hours) but by max_allowed_packet with a large INSERT statement. Changing max_allowed_packet from PHP had no effect, but when I changed it in the mysqld section of /etc/my.cnf and restarted the MySQL server, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 7):

There's a whole bunch of things that can cause this. I'd read through these and try each of them

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gone-away.html

I've worked for several web hosting companies over the years and generally when I see this, it is the wait_timeout on the server end though this doesn't appear to be the case here.

If you find the solution, I hope you post it. I'd like to know.

Comment: I went over that page a few times before posting here. Nothing seems to work. Thanks though

Answer (score 5):

This is something I do, (but usually with the MySQLi class).

```
$link = mysql_connect("$MYSQL_Host","$MYSQL_User","$MYSQL_Pass");
mysql_select_db($MYSQL_db, $link);

// RUN REALLY LONG QUERY HERE

// Reconnect if needed

if( !mysql_ping($link) ) $link = mysql_connect("$MYSQL_Host","$MYSQL_User","$MYSQL_Pass", true);

// RUN ANOTHER QUERY
```

Comment: This answer works for me but in "if" section we have to again put mysql_select_db because in other way there is an mysql error that no db is selected.

Comment: Be sure to re-run any session configuration queries (such as `SET time_zone='+00:00'`) when reconnecting, if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Increasing SQL-Wait-Timeout worked for me in this case, try this:

```
mysql_query("SET @@session.wait_timeout=900", $link);
```

before you first "normal" SQL queries.

Comment: Liked this answer. Just wondering how can I add it to a global wp query:  $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID,blah,blah, blah..                           Is it possible to add it to $wpdb or the $link/$conn themselves ? Thank you very much in advance for anybody who can clarify this more..

Comment: I think there is no special config for 'on_connect' Commands.
but cou can simply write a own connection function, what is creating the basic connection and sending your changes of connection settings.

Answer (score 3):

My case was a database corruption after a minor upgrade in mysql basically 5.0.x to 5.1.x
with the DB in myisam.
The same lines on query:
MySQL server has gone away 
Error reading result set's header

After repairing & optimizing it with mysqlcheck, it returned to normal, without the need to change the socket timeout.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with

```
if( !mysql_ping($link) ) $link = mysql_connect("$MYSQL_Host","$MYSQL_User","$MYSQL_Pass", true);
```

Comment: Are you *really sure* that you are having the exact problem OP asks about? Also can you name the drawback (cons) your solution has?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with mysqli. 
My solution is https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php

```
mysqli.reconnect = On
```

Comment: Beware: this setting is ignored by the mysqlnd driver.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed something perhaps relevant.

I had two scripts running, both doing rather slow queries. One of them locked a table and the other had to wait. The one that was waiting had default_socket_timeout = 300. Eventually it quit with "MySQL server has gone away". However, the mysql process list continued to show both query, the slow one still running and the other locked and waiting.

So I don't think mysqld is the culprit. Something has changed in the php mysql client. Quite possibly the default_socket_timeout which I will now set to -1 to see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1):

In our case, the culprit was the **global** (not "local") MySQL variable "**wait_timeout**".

Compare the results of the following queries:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%wait%';
```

to

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE '%wait%';
```

In our case the first query showed a **wait_timeout** of 28800, but the 2nd query showed a value of 10 (seconds).

We verified that changing the global variable fixed the problem.  Here is a simple PHP script that reproduced our condition:

```
<?php    
$db = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');

sleep(10); // number of seconds to sleep

// MySQL server has gone away?
$obj = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM some_table');

$results = mysqli_fetch_object($obj);

print_r($results);
```

As soon as the sleep time exceeded the global wait_timeout value, we would get the error: "Warning: mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away".

To change the value, we had to edit the setting in our Amazon RDS dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently. I stumbled across an option: `default_authentication_plugin`

For some reason it had set it to `caching_sha2_password`, but updating the value to `mysql_native_password` fixed it for me. I'm not sure what the differences are, though, so be careful!

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble on a database restore using mysqldumper (php program). I was able to get it working by changing the "mssql.timeout" setting in the php.ini.  It was defaulted to 60 and I changed it to 300.

Answer (score 0):

It happens if the connection was open for quite sometime but no action was done in the MySQL server. In that case, connection timeout occurs with the error "MySQL server has gone away". The answers above may work and may not work. Even the accepted answer did not work for me. So I tried a trick and it worked fine for me. Logically, in order to avoid this error, we have to keep the MySQL connection running or in short, *keep it alive*. Assume that we are trying to *Bulk* insert 250k records. Generally it takes time to create parse data from somewhere and make *Bulk* query and then insert. In this scenario, most of us use a loop to create the SQL string. So let's count the iteration number and make a dummy database call after a certain iteration. It will keep the connection alive.

```
for(int i = 0, size = somedatalist.length; i < size; ++i){

     // build the Bulk insert query string

     if((i%10000)==0){
         // make a dummy call like `SELECT * FROM log LIMIT 1`
         // it will keep the connection alive
     }
}
// Execute bulk insert
```

Answer (score -1):

By my experiences when it happens on light queries there is a way to solve the problem. It seems when you start or restart `mysql` after `apache` this problem starts to appear and the source of the problem is confused open sockets in the `php` process. 
To solve it:

1. First restart mysql service
2. Then restart apache service

Answer (score -4):

Please see this link http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45150
seems like they moved to native MYSQL support in PHP5.3 and it has some trouble working with IPV6.
Try using "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost"

Comment: -1 for what? for presenting a different view point? I love SO

Comment: I agree -2 is a bit harsh but the OP did say this: "The query is slow but runs as part of a nightly job so that's not a problem in itself (so please don't suggest I optimize it)."