# mysql server has gone away - not timeout error or crash

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using WAMP (Apache 2.2.11, MySQL 5.1.36, PHP 5.3.0) to write a PHP web application that has a link to a MySQL database.

I run a procedure that takes about 2 minutes in Toad to execute. If i try to run it in the PHP application, i got the errors "MySQL server has gone away in...", "Error reading result set's header", and "maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded"

I upped mysql.connect_timeout to 600 (using ini_set) and default_socket_timeout to 600 (as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644432/mysql-server-has-gone-away-in-exactly-60-seconds). This solved the timeout error, but i still get the first two.

I tried setting max_input_time to -1, and on the MySQL server side, i upped max_allowed_packet to 256M. Neither of these solved the problem.

Are there any other ways to bypass this error without altering the MySQL procedure being run?

when the webpage is loaded:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 600);//for long queries
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 600);//for long queries
//ini_set('max_input_time',-1); //don't know what this does
```

when a query is called:

```
if($reconnect===true){
  $this->disconnectDB();
}
$this->connectToDB();
if($this->selectDB($dbName)===FALSE){
  return false;
}
if(mysql_ping($this->con)===false){
  return array();           
}
$result = mysql_query($query,$this->con); //this is where the connection "goes away"
```

Comment: Can you show us your code (either here or in a paste)?

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of a PHP setting: `maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded`. Put set_time_limit(0) to disable the time limit when you need to.

`MySQL server has gone away in...` can be the result of several things. Including a MySQL crash. You may want to look at mysql logs for clues.

Comment: as you can see from the code i included above, i already have a set_time_limit(0) line. mysql.log in wamp/logs does not have any added entries after the connection goes away.

Comment: Can you correctly run the query directly through the mysql client successfully?