# INSERT: inserting multiple rows at once, or one by one?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm inserting multiple rows in a table, and I get this message:

> MySQL server has gone away

My Query:

```
INSERT INTO table
 (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k) 
     VALUES(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11),(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11), ...
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
          c=VALUES(c),
          d=VALUES(d),
          e=VALUES(e),
          f=VALUES(f),
          g=VALUES(g),
          h=VALUES(h),
          i=VALUES(i),
          j=VALUES(j)
```

Is it because I stuffed too many values inside a single query? (There are like 5000 pairs of values from a array which I implode with `,`).

If this is the reason - then should I insert each row one by one? Is it slower than inserting them all at once?

---

The PHP code:

```
foreach($data as &$entry)
 $entry = "('".implode("','", array(
   $entry->ID,
   addslashes($entry->field_1),
   addslashes($entry->field_2),
   ...

 ))."')";

$data = implode(',', $data);   

$query = "... VALUES{$data} ON ..."
```

`$data` is a array of STD type objects...

---

edit again :)

So I tried splitting my `$data` into smaller arrays of 100 elements each:

```
$data_chunks = array_chunk($data, 100);
foreach($data_chunks as $data_chunk)
  insert_into_db($data_chunk);
```

and it works, I don't get that error anymore...

So that means the issue was the very long query string...

Now I'm even more confused:

- Is there a length limit of the query, or maybe PHP arguments in general?
- Is there any difference between inserting row by row than inserting multiple rows? Is it worth the array_chunk() ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL server has gone away - in exactly 60 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644432/mysql-server-has-gone-away-in-exactly-60-seconds) ... yes it is because of the time mysql needs to process your query. Reset the value like in the linked question to a higher value like 300 and test it again.

Comment: but my query fails after only 2-3 seconds

Comment: Show some of the code around your query, then... it isn't automatically caused by a long query. Maybe you're doing a for..each loop and closing the link after the first iteration? Let's see some of your PHP.

Comment: @cularis I added `@ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 300);` and `    @ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);`, and nothing changes

Comment: regarding my 2nd question, found [this](http://kaiv.wordpress.com/2007/07/19/faster-insert-for-multiple-rows/) article

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it could be that your query is taking too long to complete, mysql times out and closes the connection. You can alter the system variables to wait longer.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with *max_allowed_packet*, although the error seems to point in different direction. Try doing as suggested here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html

Or, before making any changes to mysql configuration, simply strlen() your query and find out how long(in bytes) it actually is.