# MySQL Error 2006: MySQL Server has gone away while executing cron job

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-2006

I knew this error occurs when server restart or bandwidth issue. But we have unlimited bandwidth and server is not going restart. I'm unable to trace why I'm getting this error.

This error occurs only when i run cron job on the server. I've set cron job for every 10 min to perform few calculations and update tables.

```
protocol_version : 10
version : 5.1.65-cll
version_comment : MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine : x86_64
version_compile_os : unknown-linux-gnu
```

Please help.

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away

Comment: This can also happen if the MySQL server, process or thread abnormally terminates.  What SQL are you running, and what MySQL version are you using?  Be specific, please.

Comment: protocol_version:10, version: 5.1.65-cll, version_comment: MySQL Community Server (GPL), version_compile_machine: x86_64 and version_compile_os: unknown-linux-gnu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual issue was with my count of queries executing. About 50000 queries were executing for every 10 min so server was going away. I've reduced the limit and time interval, it is working fine now.

Thanks for your answers, it also helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into a similar situation cron job that took a while to run (ran nightly, updating reporting tables). The fix was to increase the mysql.connect_timeout and default_socket_timeout in the my.conf file. Alternately, you could use ini_set to set these values at the script level if you cannot/do not want to change it server-wide.

Also see this SO post as it deals with exactly the same thing:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1644572/1867941

Answer (score 2):

To prevent these kinds of problem, you should create a presistent connection and check if the connection exists(and reconnect) before running each query.

Comment: I'm running 13 update queries. Is it good to check connection exists each time? will there be no performance degradation?