# 60 sec timeout, unable to find the right param to fix it

Tags: php, timeout

My website exits (error 500) if a script takes more than 60 sec to be executed, but i don't understand why.

**Phpinfo:**

```
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
```

In my **httpd.conf** file:

```
timeout = 600
```

So i don't get how to increase this parameter.

I found in my phpinfo (but i have no idea if it's related or not):

```
default_socket_timeout = 60
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
```

I think the `mysql.connect_timeout` is not related at all (i got the error on a page with a `sleep(65);` only...)

Comment: It could still be related if you opened the connection and then slept for 65 without closing it. Also maybe try set_time_limit() in the script it self

Comment: Here is the PHP code of the page i use to test :

<?php

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 6000);

if($_GET['sleep'] != '')
 sleep($_GET['sleep']);

?>

(so there is no mysql connection used in this page at all)

Comment: Apache or nginx? Thinking that it may be one of them then?

Comment: If you're using Amazon to host your website and using their Load Balancing solution, it has a timeout limit of 60s

Comment: @We0 I'm using Apache. Could it be something related with apache except timeout conf in httpd.conf ?

Comment: @DougAmos I have a dedicated server at OVH

Comment: @DougAmos Apache has its own timeout, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#timeout, but is usually 300 seconds. If it isn't that then post us your phpinfo();

Comment: @We0 Here is my phpinfo : 
https://www.eden-pme.com/phpinfo.php

Comment: And this happens even when you are running the most basic of scripts? With just a sleep(65); ?

Comment: @We0 yes, as shown earlier, just a sleep(65), with a set_time_limit(0) and ini_set(default_socket_timeout)...

Comment: @Frederic I am not sure, but I think it has nothing to do with a time out, has to be something else. Eg: after x amount of time you run out of memory or apache crashes or something. If all else fails, re-install both

Comment: @We0 may be something related to memory allocated to apache ? i'll try to look for these kind of conf param for apache

Comment: Honestly no idea, can't see anything wrong with configs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finaly found the answer !

I will share the answer since i think it may help someone else !

I found in the apache error_log the following :

```
[Tue Jul 09 15:17:47 2013] [warn] [client 212.198.111.252] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds
[Tue Jul 09 15:17:47 2013] [error] [client 212.198.111.252] Premature end of script headers: test_max_execution.php
```

I then modified a file located in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ named fcgid.conf
I increased 3 parameters (FcgidIOtimeout, FcgidIdleTimeout & FcgidConnectTimeout) and everything seems to work properly now !

Have a nice day and thank you for paying attention to my question !

Frederic

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at…

- [PHP set_time_limit()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)
- [PHP Runtime Configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php)

…and:

- [MySQL server has gone away - in exactly 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1644432/2493918)

Happy reading :-)